# Python - получение всех переменных класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-3.5

Есть класс:
class Class1():

```
value1 = {"value1": "v"}
value2 = {"value2": "v"}
```

Следующий класс:
class Class2(Class1):

```
value3 = "value3"
value4 = {Class1} - тут хочу положить value1 и value2 в словарь
```

Затем, в тесте вызываю Class2:

```
t = Class2()
```

В итоге t равно:

```
{"value3": "value3", {<class "путь-к-классу.Class1">}}
```

Подскажите, как получить?

```
{"value3": "value3", {{"value1": "v"}, {"value2": "v"}}}
```

---

В ответе, кроме упомянутых значений, также присутствуют такие парамтры как:

```
     mappingproxy, 
     "init": <function Class1.__init__ at 0x7f9a88d21a60>, 
     "module": "path_to_class", 
     "_meta": <meta_data>, 
     "doc": null
```

Было бы здорово избежать их появления

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В python у классов есть есть атрибут `__dict__`или метод`vars(obj)` они возвращают все переменные ОБЪЕКТА, это значит, сто если вы объявит ваши переменные  в **init** как `self.value1' и 'self.value2`, то при создании объекта класса Class1 на пример:

```
'a = Class1()
print( a.__dict__ )  # или vars()
#вывод  {'value1' : {'value1' : 'v'}, 'value2' : {'value2' :'v'}`
```

Для доступа к value1 напишите: a.**dict** [0] или  a.**dict** ['value1']

А вообще, мне не понятен вопрос для доступа к полям есть оператор "." Для доступа к дому полю или метод класса нужна написать его через точку например: 
    `a.value1` вернет {'value1':'v'}

Comment: Для получения результата точно как у вас в желаемом сделайте `value4 = Class1().__dict__', но перед этим не забудьте сделать у класса поля полями класса, самый простой способ в конструкторе напишите: `self.value1={"value1": "v"}` и и тоже самое для value2

Comment: Я не уверен, но возможно vars(Class1) вернет нужные вам переменные без вышеуказанной поправки, тестите

Comment: class Class1:
    def _init_(self):
        self.value1 = {"value1": "v"}
        self.value1 = {"value1": "v"}


value4 = Class1()._dict_


Результат:

value4 = [{Class1._dict_}]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'mappingproxy'

в чём ошибка?

Comment: Разобрался, почему была ошибка - нужно было убрать массив 
Теперь со значения мне приходят такие вещи как mappingproxy, "__init__": <function Class1.__init__ at 0x7f9a88d21a60>, "__module__": "path_to_class", "_meta": <meta_data>, "__doc__": null}

Comment: НО, только вот так

print( a.()__dict__ )  # или vars(a())

Comment: Ответ ниже помог?

Answer (score 0):

Вы видимо исправить эту конструкцию для КЛАССА а нужно для объекта, если выполнить данный код то все заработает :
    `a = Class1()
     print(a.__dict__)`
В первой строке вы создаёте объект а восвторой для него вызываете метод **dict** который возвращает только переменные без всякого дишнего, (заметьте, что во второй строке после объекта "а" круглые скобки не нужны, ведь это и есть объект класса, а вот если вы вызовите 
     `Class1.__dict__` то получить как раз то что вы и получали с лишними полями docs, meta и т.п.